# C# - System.Web.HttpParseException error when having unclosed HTML elements inside an @if

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, razor, runtime-error

I have a simple HTML which changes depending of `topic.IsScheduled`'s value *(bool)*:

#### if false:

```
+-------------------+-------------------+
|     row-fluid                         |
+-------------------+-------------------+
| span6(something1) | span6(something2) |
+-------------------+-------------------+
```

#### if true:

```
+-------------------+-------------------+
|     row-fluid                         |
+-------------------+-------------------+
| span6(something1) | span6(something3) |
+-------------------+-------------------+
|     row-fluid                         |
+-------------------+-------------------+
| span6(something2) | span6(something4) |
+-------------------+-------------------+
```

The razor/cshtml:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span6">
            something1
        </div>
    @if (topic.IsScheduled){
        <div class="span6">
            something3
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
    }
        <div class="span6">
            something2
        </div>
    @if (topic.IsScheduled) {
        <div class="span6">
            something4
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

But when I do this, I get the following error when running the project:

```
System.Web.HttpParseException (0x80004005): The if block is missing a closing "}" character. Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all the "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" characters are being interpreted as markup. at
```

I've tested and C# is giving me errors because `div`s aren't closed inside the `@if` statement, *not because of missing opening/closing brackets*. If I close them inside the if, or simply comment the entire if with `@* *@`, then it works.

#### How can I configure to ignore `HttpParse` or even turn it off so stops parsing my HTML?

*Yes, I can make the if/else but then I'll have duplicated HTML and variables because parser is dumb, which I wanted to avoid.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, HTML elements and Razor code blocks must be properly nested, so when the parser gets to the second `</div>` inside your `@if`, it thinks you forgot the closing `}`.

To fix the error, simply prefix the "extra" HTML tags with `@:` like so:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6">
        something1
    </div>
@if (topic.IsScheduled) {
    <div class="span6">
        something3
    </div>
@:</div>
@:<div class="row-fluid">
}
    <div class="span6">
        something2
    </div>
@if (topic.IsScheduled) {
    <div class="span6">
        something4
    </div>
}
</div>
```

The `@:` sequence tells the parser that the rest of line is content which you want to include as part of the containing code block.

Comment: That worked nicely. `@:` acts something like PHP's `echo` but without having to wrap on quotes, right? Thanks!

Comment: @RaphaelDDL: I'm afraid I'm not familiar with PHP. Perhaps someone else can comment.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good but the Razor layout engine doesn't exactly have all the kinks worked out of it yet, and you did get a little fancy with your layout/biz logic. That said, have you tried the KISS method? Thusly:

```
@if (topic.IsScheduled){
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span6">something1</div>
        <div class="span6">something3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span6">something2</div>
            <div class="span6">something4</div>
    </div>
} else {
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span6">something1</div>
        <div class="span6">something2</div>
    </div>
}
```

I've experienced all sorts of weirdness with Razor such as white space (or lack thereof) causing an exception at runtime.